# Не работает часть стилей

Tags: html, css

всем неравнодушным! Заранее благодарю за помощь или желание помочь.
Есть сайт: https://lucklife-business.ru/

Я не очень давно занимаюсь сайтами, поэтому возникает много, может быть, слишком простых вопросов. На сайте прописаны в стилях прилипание меню сверху при прокрутке с помощью фиксации, кнопка вверх и еще в футере тоже используется в стилях фиксация. Он как бы выезжает из-под верхних блоков.

Но всё это я вижу только у себя локально. После переноса на хостинг эти свойства исчезают. Обновляю с ctrl+f5, на хостинге нет кеша, переписывалась с ними. На других компьютерах тоже самое - не показывается кнопка вверх, нет прилипания меню и т.д.

Еще прописывала прелоадер. Он работал локально. Но на хостинге не исчезал загрузочный элемент и сайт так и не начинал показываться. Поэтому закомментировала его.

Не знаю, с какой стороны к этому подойти. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Начните с того, что опубликуйте достаточный фрагмент кода в вопросе, чтобы его можно было запустить и увидеть проблему. Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..."

Comment: Благодарю за ваш интерес! Нашла решение)

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Comment: Я поняла на будущее) Тут пришлось бы весь сайт выкладывать, потому что мне непонятно было, где что-то не так. Что-то работало, что-то нет. И на локалке всё работало. Я очень рада, что всё разрешилось) Очень нужно было)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю, может быть, кому-то будет полезно. Не пользовалась до этого консолью в браузере. Воспользовалась впервые. Вызов по правой кнопки мыши - Просмотреть код.

У моего хостинга есть болезнь. Он большие буквы в файлах делает маленькими. Поэтому при копировании на хостинг, изменился регистр в названиях файлов, а, значит, и путь к ним. Перестали подгружаться файлы с большими буквами в названии. Без консоли я этого не увидела. Видела, что часть работает, и не могла понять, что не так.

Исправила все названия на маленькие буквы, и всё заработало.

Удачи всем!